# ¿Qué es el cuñadismo?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, españa, coloquialismos

El otro día en un correo de un amigo de España él me decía:

> [eso que me cuentas] es un claro ejemplo de "**cuñadismo**"

y explicaba a continuación

> Es un término que se ha puesto de moda por España. Si no lo conoces, te invito a que busques el término por internet. Te echarás unas risas e identificarás a varios "cuñaos" que te habrás topado por la vida

Lo curioso es que yo en la anécdota hacía referencia a mi suegro, no a mi cuñado, así que entiendo que el término se refiere más a un tipo de personaje en general, que a un tipo de cuñado (es decir, que tu primo, la novia de tu hermano, y ese amigo que conoces de toda la vida pueden ser también *cuñadísimos*).

El otro día vi el *palabro* usado otra vez en [una web de cine](http://www.lashorasperdidas.com/index.php/2016/12/14/trailer-y-poster-de-es-por-tu-bien/) donde describían el argumento de una nueva película como:

> Los tres dan vida a una terna de padres, *cuñadísimos*, horrorizados con los tres novios de sus hijas, a los que tratarán de sacar de sus vidas de la forma que haga falta

Y entiendo que aunque los protagonistas puedan (o no) ser cuñados, el término *cuñadísimos* se refiere más a su personalidad (que supongo que es lo que va a dar pie a situaciones humorísticas la película) que a su relación familiar.

Y como mi amigo bien dice, llevo ya un tiempo fuera de España y algunos de estos términos son casi alienígenas para mí...

¿Me explica alguien lo que es el `cuñadismo` y lo que es un *'cuñao / cuñado / cuñadísimo'* en ese sentido?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En el blog [Noticias desde la Antártida](http://noticiasdesdelaantartida.blogspot.com.es/2014/01/el-cunadismo.html) lo explicaban así en 2014 (he entresacado algunos párrafos de la entrada):

> El cuñadismo es una forma de vida practicada originalmente por cuñados y que se ha generalizado a gran parte de la sociedad.
>   ....
>   Un ‘cuñado’ (y entiéndase este término genérico como referido a aquella persona animal o cosa que practica el cuñadismo) lo sabe todo, lo hace todo bien, y lo que es peor, se empeña en restregártelo constantemente por los morros. El tema de conversación favorito de un cuñado es él mismo.
>   ...
>   Los cuñados se entrenan en el arte de la dialéctica frente a un muro de hormigón. De hecho ellos solo necesitan una frase, o a veces ni tan siquiera eso, les basta con una palabra, para tener una puerta de entrada a su propio discurso. De repente te preguntas ‘Pero ¿cómo he terminado en medio de una conferencia sobre el ataque de la 101 aerotransportada al Nido del Águila, si yo lo que estaba comentando es lo de este bultito que me ha salido?’. Eso amigos, es una conversación con un cuñado.
>   ...
>   El cuñado sabe encontrar el fallo en todos tus argumentos y darles la vuelta de forma que se vea bien claro que eres gilipollas. De hecho la frase favorita de un cuñado es 'si es que no tienes ni puta idea'.
>   ...
>   Un cuñado sabe más que nadie de bricolaje, mecánica, fútbol, historia antigua y hasta de física cuántica si hace falta. Y si un cuñado no sabe algo, es que es una mierda que no tiene la menor importancia ...

Answer (score 4):

A mí también me ha resultado curioso el surgimiento del término *cuñado* para referirse al paladín del sentido común, pero con un toque grotesco, rancio y sobradillo.

Este rol hace un tiempo que lo veo en producciones de Hollywood: un personaje principal es frecuentemente ninguneado por un cuñado con un carácter más dicharachero y sociable, pero a la vez de una simplicidad máxima y una capacidad de simplificar los problemas hasta límites perversamente maniqueos. Así a vuelapluma se me ocurre el cuñado del protagonista de [Breaking Bad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_Bad), un policía sin demasiadas luces que lo deja en ridículo con sus comentarios (corregidme si me equivoco, pues apenas he visto un par de capítulos de esta serie).

En España últimamente es un concepto muy utilizado para despreciar los planteamientos de alguien. Por ejemplo, [el diputado Gabriel Rufián intervino en el Congreso de los Diputados de octubre de 2016, durante la sesión de investidura del Presidente del Gobierno](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aE5AGeWJg-Q). En esa intervención llamó "cuñados" a los diputados de un partido político como forma de tachar sus propuestas como simplistas.

Tanto ha crecido el concepto que incluso Fundéu lo recogió recientemente en [*cuñadismo, nuevo significado*](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/cunadismo-nuevo-significado/) (un par de días antes de tu pregunta, casualmente):

> El término cuñadismo, que hasta ahora hacía referencia al nepotismo o favoritismo hacia los cuñados, ha ampliado su significado y se emplea sobre todo para referirse a la tendencia a opinar sobre cualquier asunto, queriendo aparentar ser más listo que los demás.
>
> Empieza a ser habitual encontrar en los medios frases como las siguientes: «El cuñadismo ha triunfado en España», «¿Por qué nos engancha tanto el cuñadismo en televisión?» o «Radiografía del cuñadismo español, la pandemia que martiriza un país entero», todas ellas adecuadas.
>
> Como se aprecia en estos ejemplos, este sustantivo se está empleando recientemente en España para denominar la actitud de quien aparenta saber de todo, habla sin saber pero imponiendo su opinión o se esfuerza por mostrar a los demás lo bien que hace las cosas.
>
> El Diccionario del español actual de Seco, Andrés y Ramos definía cuñadismo, en su edición de 1999, como el ‘nepotismo que recae sobre un cuñado’ («Los matrimonios políticos producen cuñadismo político»), esto es, con un significado muy próximo a amiguismo.
>
> Es probable que el nuevo significado de cuñadismo obedezca a las características que popularmente suelen atribuirse a los cuñados, si bien el término no se circunscribe al ámbito familiar, pues se emplea de manera amplia en relación con cualquier persona que muestre esos rasgos.
>
> Se trata de una voz coloquial, aunque no es raro encontrarla en medios de comunicación y hasta en tribunas políticas. No precisa comillas, al menos en España, donde el término se halla muy extendido y resulta de fácil comprensión.

Siguiendo con la componente jocosa, el periódico digital eldiario.es sacó estas Navidades el ['bingo cuñao antifeminista' para las cenas de Navidad](http://www.eldiario.es/sociedad/bingo-cunao-antifeminista-cenas-Navidad_0_593891389.html). Bajo las frases:

> ¿Y los hombres maltratados qué?, ni machismo ni feminismo, igualdad...Aquí van algunas frases que seguramente escuches en tus cenas de Navidad si te atreves a hablar de feminismo
>
> Comparte tus resultados en redes sociales con el hashtag #bingocuñao

Invitaban a utilizar el siguiente "cartón" para ir marcando toda una serie de tópicos antifeministas cuando el presunto cuñado los mencionara durante una cena familiar. Lo copio aquí porque resulta bastante representativo sobre el tipo de frases con que se asocia a los cuñados: simplistas, con un sesgo de pretendido sentido común.

> [image]

Como colofón, me ha hecho especial gracia el estudio al respecto que se hace en el artículo [*La cuñadez simétrica*](http://www.antoniorico.es/2016/12/la-cunadez-simetrica.html), en el que cae en una cosa por otra parte evidente: si llamas a alguien cuñado, es porque tú lo eres de él:

> Ten cuidado de a quién llamas cuñado. Porque si él es tu cuñado, tú eres el cuñado de él. No ocurría lo mismo antes, cuando la pariente maldita era la suegra. Con los parentescos asimétricos uno puede acusar sin quedar atrapado en la acusación, pero los parentescos simétricos te enredan con los mismos atributos de aquél al que calificas.
>
> (...) el hombre es un cuñado para el hombre. El cuñado ha dejado de ser un pariente para convertirse en una forma de ser cuya principal característica es que nadie se la atribuye a sí mismo, por más que tal autoatribución es inherente a su definición.

Comment: Muy interesante, gracias. Estoy sorprendido por la amplia presencia de este término en la red. Me encanta esa advertencia final: "Ten cuidado de a quién llamas cuñado. Porque si él es tu cuñado, tú eres el cuñado de él". Ya lo decía Nietzsche, “Quien con monstruos lucha cuide de convertirse a su vez en monstruo. Cuando miras largo tiempo a un abismo, el abismo también mira dentro de ti.” :-D

Answer (score -1):

El cuñadisimo se refiere a Ramón Serrano Suñer, mano derecha de Franco y que efectivamente era su cuñado. Se refiere a alguien que tiene poder y que ha obtenido cualquier tipo de beneficio por ser pariente o conocer a alguien importante.
Pues Ramón Serrano Suñer mientras estuvo en el cargo gozó de todo tipo de beneficios para su empresa al ser el cuñado de Franco

Comment: Efectivamente, a Ramón Serrano Suñer se le conocía como _el cuñadísimo_, pues era cuñado de Carmen Polo, la mujer de Franco. Sin embargo, dudo que la acepción de "cuñadismo" por la que se pregunta tenga algo que ver con este personaje. Me remito a la cita de fedorqui en su respuesta, que es el concepto que yo tengo de cuñadismo: "se emplea sobre todo para referirse a la tendencia a opinar sobre cualquier asunto, queriendo aparentar ser más listo que los demás".

Comment: Exacto, tal y como dice @Charlie el problema aquí radica en una "i": cuñadismo - cuñadísimo. Aquí se pregunta por lo primero y esta respuesta nos habla de lo segundo